# Newbie to python getting error NameError: name 'employeeList' is not defined

Tags: python

[In this pastebin link I have written python program to do ask for name,ID and job title and then return data.](http://pastebin.com/9eMB0epY)

But, whenever I run this program it is giving me an error saying "

> line 50, in  for employee in employeeList: NameError: name
>   'employeeList' is not defined

"

I pasted code on pastebin because stackoverflow was removing indentation from code.

Please help as I have it due by tomorrow for semester project

Comment: your indentation is all screwed up ... thats why it doesnt work ...

Comment: Thank you could you help somehow?

Comment: I recommend using a good ide ... something like pycharm ... it will tell you about these problems and suggest fixes

Comment: See "[Markdown Help: Code and Preformatted Text](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)" for help on indenting code blocks.

Comment: Please (re-)read "[ask]", then [edit] your question to include a [mcve], so that your question will remain useful to others even after that Paste Bin text vanishes.  (Note:  I suspect this will end up closed as a "[simple typographical error](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" (#2), but it might not.)

Comment: See also:  Eric Lippert's "[How To Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)".

Comment: PS:  You don't need Java-style getters and setters in Python.

Comment: Please post your code inside your question rather than on an external site like pastebin. [edit] your question to include it. Please try to reduce your code to the smallest program that will still reproduce your problem, so that you have a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

your code is all fine: it's your indentation that's messed up:

```
# starting of Employee class
class Employee(object):
    def __init__(self): #declaring Constructor
        self.name = ""
        self.iDnumber = ""
        self.department = ""
        self.jobTitle = ""

    # setter methode for setting values to the class properties
    def setName(self,name):
            self.name=name
    def setIDnumber(self,iDnumber):
            self.iDnumber=iDnumber
    def setDepartment(self,department):
            self.department=department
    def setJobTitle(self,jobTitle):
            self.jobTitle=jobTitle

    # getter methode for getting values of the class properties
    def getName(self):
            return self.name
    def getIDnumber(self):
            return self.iDnumber
    def getDepartment(self):
            return self.department
    def getJobTitle(self):
            return self.jobTitle

    # methode which takes object as an argument and display its properties
    def display(emp_object):
        print("Name : ",emp_object.getName())
        print("IDnumber : ",emp_object.getIDnumber())
        print("Department : ",emp_object.getDepartment())
        print("JobTitle : ",emp_object.getJobTitle())

# Main methode of the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    employeeList = [] #List to hold the Employee objects
    emp1 = Employee()
    emp2 = Employee()
    emp3 = Employee()

    # appending objects to the list
    employeeList.append(emp1)
    employeeList.append(emp2)
    employeeList.append(emp3)
    input()

    # Initializing each objects of the list
    for employee in employeeList:
        emp_name = input("Enter your Name ")
        employee.setName(emp_name)
        emp_iDnumber = input("Enter your iDnumber ")
        employee.setIDnumber(emp_iDnumber)
        emp_department = input("Enter your Department ")
        employee.setDepartment(emp_department)
        emp_jobTitle = input("Enter your JobTitle ")
        employee.setJobTitle(emp_jobTitle)

    # Displaying each objects of the list
    for emp_object in employeeList:
        display(emp_object)
```

output:

```
Enter your Name viki
Enter your iDnumber 1
Enter your Department a
Enter your JobTitle b
Enter your Name viki2
Enter your iDnumber 2
Enter your Department b
Enter your JobTitle c
Enter your Name viki3
Enter your iDnumber 3
Enter your Department a
Enter your JobTitle b
Name :  viki
IDnumber :  1
Department :  a
JobTitle :  b
Name :  viki2
IDnumber :  2
Department :  b
JobTitle :  c
Name :  viki3
IDnumber :  3
Department :  a
JobTitle :  b
```

notes:

use method names like `get_name` or `set_name` instead of `setName`. you can also use `property-decorator` : [How does the @property decorator work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work)

PS: Also go through the comments on your questions, There are really good suggestions that will help you improve your coding ability once you are done with your semester.